# Python AF_BLUETOOTH socket for Bluetooth, how to disable buffer / have equivalent behavior to TCP_NODELAY?

Tags: python, sockets, bluetooth, buffer

Trying to use AF_BLUETOOTH sockets in Python, and it seems that they buffer output like other types of socket, but there seems to be no way to disable it, unlike with TCP.

Reference code:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_BLUETOOTH, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.BTPROTO_RFCOMM)
s.connect((address, port))
for line in sys.stdin:
    s.send(bytes(line, 'UTF-8'), flags)
    print(f"Sent '{line}'", file=sys.stderr)
```

It seems to print in the client just fine, but the server doesn't receive anything until the client closes (either by EOF or Ctrl-C).

Tried to use

```
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_SNDBUF, 0)
```

from another suggestion here, but that didn't help. Since AF_BLUETOOTH seems to be exclusively a Python thing, there aren't many resources online.

Edit: add repro example

Client

```
import socket

address = '00:00:00:00:00:00'
port = 5
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_BLUETOOTH, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.BTPROTO_RFCOMM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_SNDBUF, 0) #attempt to instant send
s.connect((address, port))
for line in sys.stdin:
  s.send(bytes(line, 'utf-8'))
s.close()
```

Server

```
import socket

address = '00:00:00:00:00:00'
port = 5
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_BLUETOOTH, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.BTPROTO_RFCOMM)
s.bind((address, port))

s.listen(1)
client, address = s.accept()

while True:
  data = client.recv(1024)
  if data:
    print(str(data, 'UTF-8'))
  else:
    break

s.close()
```

Comment: Show a [mcve] of the server and client.  [From what I read](https://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/x502.html) it should work like TCP with the exception of creating the socket so the problem may be in code not shown.  Even without Nagle disabled TCP sends data, just a tiny bit slower due to waiting for more data to coalesce into fewer packets.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could publish a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For examples, what are you setting `flags` to on the `send`? Bluetooth is very closely linked with the operating system so it would also be helpful it you said what OS you are doing this on. I've not seen the problem you speak of when I've implemented SPP servers on Linux and Windows. I've often pointed people at https://blog.kevindoran.co/bluetooth-programming-with-python-3/ which seems to work.

Comment: Will add a repro, my bad. Also did follow that blog post, as that is the basis of what I tried, but no luck.

Comment: Done, added repro